# Formatting DateTime to string with timezone information for Date created in Javascript

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api

In this massively oversimplified example, I have a controller method that accepts a DateTime

```
[Route("api/demo)]
public IHttpActionResult Post(DateTime date)
{
   // format dateTime here
}
```

We call this from the client with Javascript.

```
var data = {
    date: new Date()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/demo",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

The `new Date()` part is what I feel is the important part, as we're trying to record the date as the calling client sees it (their local time)

What is the best way to format the DateTime object as a string, so that it records the timezone information, and can be parsed back into a `DateTime` object again later if required?

(We're storing this formatted string in an analytics recording platform / data warehouse)

Comment: You really don't care what timezone the data was stored, only the local time.  If you enter date in NY at 9:00AM and you are in California don't you want to see 6:00AM and not 9:00AM?

Comment: If you want to include a TimeZone use DateTimeOffset, not DateTime

Comment: Use `DateTimeOffset` as your action parameter and make sure dates are sent in the ISO8601 format, eg '2014-05-06T22:24:55Z'. You won't have to convert anything in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to perform any conversions, just change the parameter type to [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[Route("api/demo)]
public IHttpActionResult Post(DateTimeOffset date)
{
    //use the date without conversions.
}
```

JSON.stringify serializes the date using the ISO8601 format (eg `"2017-01-10T14:52:04.780Z"`) which can be parsed directly to a DateTimeOffset. DateTimeOffset allows you to compare values with different offsets directly, removing the need to convert to the same timezone

By using DateTimeOffset you avoid the confusion between local and UTC DateTime values. Without knowing the timezone offset you don't really know what "local" refers to - the client's or the server's timezone?

Comment: thanks - but how to we `ToString` the `date` param? Just `.ToString()` ? Reason being, is this is being saved into third party that is expecting a string

Comment: @Alex Just use `ToString()` or `String.Format()` in the same way you would with `DateTime`. If the other service understands ISO8601 you can use the value as is. If it expects UTC only you can get the date as UTC by calling [ToUniversalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) first.

Comment: @Alex is that third party a database? Some databases, eg SQL Server have a `datetimeoffset` type that allows storing the offset as well.

Comment: no, it's Keen.io - essentially a nosql database, but only accepts text really. So looking at storing the .tostring of the offset

Comment: according to this - https://keen.io/docs/data-collection/data-modeling-guide/#iso-8601-format it wants an iso-8601 date (with time zone, otherwise it'll store it as UTC)

Comment: Keen.io also accepts ISO8601. Just make sure you use the correct format string, eg `o`

Answer (score 0):

You can use new Date().getTimezoneOffset() in javascript to know the difference between the current time zone of the client and the UTC. It offset will be in minute. Example - TimezoneOffset between Singapore Time and UTC is -480 minutes.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Then create a cookie in the javascript and store that offset in it.

```
function setTimezoneCookie(){

    var timezone_cookie = "timezoneoffset";

    if (!$.cookie(timezone_cookie)) { 
        // create a new cookie 
        $.cookie(timezone_cookie, new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
    }
}
```

Every request goes to the server will carry that cookie and at server side 
convert the dateTime submitted by client to UTC by Adding the offset from cookie and save it in the database. This would ensure that no matter in what timezone user is the data will always have UTC date and time uniformly.

Also when displaying the datetime information in the UI, convert it to the client time by substracting offset retrieved from cookie before sending to the UI.

This way it will be sure that user sees the dates and time as per it's client machines timezone.

Extension methods would be handy in this case.

```
public static DateTime ToClientTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
        // read the value from session
        var timeOffSet = HttpContext.Current.Request["timezoneoffset"];

        if (timeOffSet != null)
        {
            var offset = int.Parse(timeOffSet.ToString());
            dt = dt.AddMinutes(-1 * offset);

            return dt;
        }

        // if there is no offset in session return the datetime as it is
        return dt;
    }

public static DateTime ToUtcTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
        // read the value from session
        var timeOffSet = HttpContext.Current.Request["timezoneoffset"];

        if (timeOffSet != null)
        {
            var offset = int.Parse(timeOffSet.ToString());
            dt = dt.AddMinutes(offset);

            return dt;
        }

        // if there is no offset in session return the datetime as it is

        return dt;
    }
```

This should resolve help you resolving your issue.

Comment: Instead of using an arbitrary local time (local for whom? The server?) it's better to use the DateTimeOffset class.

Comment: I have upated my code to avoid conversion to LocalTime. The method ToLocalTime will convert the UTC time to the local time of the location from where user is requesting the data. DateTimeOffset  can surely be useful if we make sure that we pass it to the server along with every request which carries DateTime..

Comment: It does. JSON.stringify serializes the date into the ISO8601 format which does contain the offset

Comment: My solution aims to make sure the dates and times store in database uniformaly and display them in current timezone of the user. If DateTimeOffset can makes that possible, I would see it less complex and preferred solution.

Comment: Then use `datetimeoffset` in the database as well

Comment: I can do that.. but what if user is requesting data from a different time zone than the original one? How user would figure out the timezone associated with the date and time displayed in the UI? What if I have to use the datetime information stored in the database to for report generaiton and analysis purporse? I will have to deal with each piece of datetime data under stand the timezone of it and relate it to something which is central.

Comment: To me there is no wrong or right solution unless it fits well the situation or do something bad. The application which I worked did have such kind of requirement so I went with the solution which I suggesed and it worked well and still working good in production environment.

Comment: Knowing the offset makes everything easier. If the client wants a different timezone? Convert it or format it to whatever is required. You can't do that if you don't actually store the offset. As for right or wrong, you probably should check NodaTime and its justification. Even knowing the offset isn't enough to deal eg with daylight savings time. Even storing everything as UTC loses information

Comment: I need to only know the offset information no need to store it. Coz I can get it from the client by the way I suggested. So when I want to show data in client's timezone I will know the timezone offset via cookie and convert UTC time to client timezone and send it to client. I would never want to deal with offset stored in database. It would simplify my queries, logic and analysis. All I need to know is all my datetime infomration which is stored in db is UTC.