# Facing issue with datetime.now in mvc5

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

i am using Dateime.Now in .net mvc and i deployed my website on europen web server when i use date someware in my website system always pick server datetime which is not best for me i want system always pick specific user coutry datettime if user locate in pakistan syetem always pick pakistan datetime or if user locate in japan system always pick japan datetime is this possiable?

Comment: You can not use DateTime.Now and expect it to be Client's DateTime. You need to know the DateTime zone of the client and adjust the value of datetime at the server based on the difference between server and client datetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting DateTime to string with timezone information for Date created in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570594/formatting-datetime-to-string-with-timezone-information-for-date-created-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save/create the datetime in the backend as `DateTime.UtcNow` to set it in utc and in the frontend convert it to local via javascript

```
new dateToLocal = new Date(dateTimeValueFromServer);
document.getElementById(idOfDateTimeElement).value = dateToLocal;
```

Comment: thanks Gabriel Llorico i think this is usefull for me thanks again

Comment: @MianBilal hi, if it did answer your problem, can you mark it as answer? thanks